# Japanese god of tea

Tags: japanese

Is there a Japanese god or goddess of tea?

I’ve read that Inari is a god of various things, such as rice, sake, and tea... But is there a deity that is god of tea in particular?

Comment: god of swordsmiths and cultivation as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding of the [Japanese tea ceremony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_tea_ceremony) is that it arose out of the Zen tradition, which has no gods.

However, I did find mention of a Japanese [kami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kami) associated with tea, [Inari Ōkami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inari_%C5%8Ckami).

There is also god of tea, [Lu Yu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lu_Yu), author of [The Classic of Tea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Classic_of_Tea), in Chinese folklore, .